# Are "map numbering systems" on-topic?

Tags: support

I think I asked a question about map-numbering systems on the main site. Either I am mistaken and I didn't finally submit the question, or it got removed — maybe it's considered offtopic.

- Would I receive a message if a question I asked gets removed (e.g. for being off-topic)?
- Would a question like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk/Archives/Miscellaneous/2010_October_28#Topographic_map_series_codes_and_layout.) be considered on-topic? I'm not too much into *GIS* and not sure if it might be too far off.

Comment: Your account record doesn't indicate you have ever asked any question.  (If it had been closed, migrated, or deleted, I would still see a record of it.)  You wouldn't necessarily get a message (as far as I know), but you should still be able to see the question title on your account page.  I think you just didn't submit the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say they're on topic.  There are already a number of [questions related to MGRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=mgrs).  Have you looked to see if the question is listed on your personal page, but with "closed" next to it?

I've always been amused at how folks at places like [Mapsco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapsco) and [Keymap](http://www.keymap.com/) define a very elegant referencing system covering a city, only to have to kludge their system when the city grows beyond the original coverage.